# Can't get the position for view inside RecylerView Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-recyclerview

My recycler view adapter is as follows

```
    @Override
        public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                    inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_item, viewGroup, false);
            return new ContactViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder viewHolder,  int position) {
            super.onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, position);
            viewHolder.removeContact.setTag(position);
            Contact contact = contacts.get(position);
            viewHolder.contactName.setText(contact.getContactName());
            viewHolder.contactNumber.setText(contact.getContactNumber());
            viewHolder.removeContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Integer taggedPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();
                Log.wtf("ad","Posirtion"+ Integer.toString(taggedPosition));
                contacts.remove(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(taggedPosition)));
                notifyItemRemoved(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(taggedPosition)));
                }
            });
        }



        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return contacts.size();
        }


        public void removeItem(int pos) {
            contacts.remove(pos);
    //      notifyItemRemoved(pos);
        }

        public void add(Contact contact, int position) {
            contacts.add(position, contact);
            notifyItemInserted(position);
        }
```

and my view holder is

```
class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

    public TextView contactName,contactNumber;
    public ImageButton removeContact;

    public ContactViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        contactName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_contactName);
        contactNumber= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_contactNumber);
        removeContact= (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ib_removeItem);
    }
}
```

The issue is i cant seem to get the postion of `viewHolder.removeContact`.All i want to achieve is to remove the row when the `viewHolder.removeContact`is clicked.I have tried getting the postion by getTag() method also but it gives me only one postion ie 0.

Comment: what value getting if using `int toggedPosition=Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())` ?

Comment: Same 0 .Also tried make the postion final ,Also getting value 0

Comment: make ContectViewHolder implement OnClickListener, thats all, no need for any setTag/getTag

Comment: @pskink i tried that but in my case i have to update my Contacts arraylist as well as myadapter which i can't if i implement inside ContactViewHolder

Comment: i dont understand what you mean, what you cannot implement inside ContactViewHolder? create ContactViewHolder as an inner class of your adapter and you can do everything you want

Comment: I can implement onClickListener inside ContactsViewHolder and get the relevant position but i have to update adapter as well as my  contacts list

Comment: so create ContactsViewHolder inside your adapter, its common case

Comment: @goonerdroid: try after moving all code inside `onCreateViewHolder` from `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: @pskink i cant do that my recycleradapter needs a seperate viewholder class

Comment: see http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview/

Comment: or if you really don't want it to be inner class pass the adapter reference to the ContactsViewHolder constructor

Comment: yes was thinking about that  but can you show me as to how send the adapter refrence.Sorry  if i am being naive

Comment: in onCreateViewHolder: return new ContactsViewHolder(yourRootView, this);

Comment: @pskink Thanks take a bow Sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink.Thanks. Solved the issue all i did was to pass the reference of my adapter and `contacts` arraylist to my view holder class like this

```
@Override
    public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new ContactViewHolder(itemView,this,contacts);
    }
```

where `itemView` is the View to be returned,`this` is the adapter refrence and `contacts` is the arraylist i have to updated on button click.My ViewHolder class loooks like this

```
class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

    public TextView contactName,contactNumber;
    public ImageButton removeContact;
    private  List<Contact> contacts1;
    private ContactsAdapter contactsAdapter1;

    public ContactViewHolder(View itemView, ContactsAdapter contactsAdapter, final List<Contact> contacts) {
        super(itemView);
        this.contacts1=contacts;
        this.contactsAdapter1=contactsAdapter;
        contactName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_contactName);
        contactNumber= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_contactNumber);
        removeContact= (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ib_removeItem);
        removeContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                contacts1.remove(getPosition());
                contactsAdapter1.notifyItemRemoved(getPosition());
            }
        });
    }
}
```